# Sails.js How to insert data into a join table (Many to Many)

Tags: node.js, orm, sails.js, waterline

I am having an error inserting data into my join table and I don't know if I'm doing it the right way.
Here are my 2 models that have the many to many association.

Commit.js:

```
module.exports = {
  schema: true,
  attributes: {
    idCommit : {
      type: 'integer',
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      unique: true
    },
    revision : {
    type: 'integer',
    required: true
    },
    issues: {
      collection: 'issue',
      via: 'commits',
      dominant: true
    }
  }
};
```

Issue.js:

```
module.exports = {
  schema: true,
  attributes: {
    idIssue : {
      type: 'integer',
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      unique: true
    },
    description: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true
    },
    commits: {
      collection: 'commit',
      via: 'issues'
    }
  }
};
```

When I try to insert issues into a commit this way :

```
Commit.create(commit).exec(function(err,created){
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  else { 
    created.issues.add(issues);
    created.save(function(err) {});
  }
});
```

My commit is created, my issues are created, but there is no link what so ever between them and the join table stays empty. Where did I get it wrong?

Comment: which adapter are you using?

Comment: The sails gitter room is also a great place to get help: https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails

Comment: I'm using the mySql adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code it looks like your trying to add an array of issues, try doing the association individually, like they do in the [Many-to-Many docs](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/ManytoMany.html)

```
Commit.create(commit).exec(function(err,created){
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  else { 

    issues.forEach(function(issue, index){
        created.issues.add(issue);
    })

    created.save(function(err) {});
  }
});
```

Comment: You can simplify by just using: `created.add(issues);`. Yes, it handles arrays to.