# Sails creating data into many to many relationship

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I currently have two collections, which are `Schools` and `Contacts`. The `Schools` collection has already been populated with thousand of data while `Contacts` is a new collection which is still empty.

Now there's a schema change for both of them. Here's the schema detail:

```
// ----------- Schools.js
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    user: {
      model: 'users'
      // Của User đã tạo
    },

    essential: {
      type: 'string'
      // Lưu toàn bộ thông tin của essential
    },

    contacts: {
      collection: 'contacts',
      via: 'schools'
    },

    pipeline: {
        type: 'string',
        defaultTo: ""
    },

    status: {
      type: 'integer',
      defaultsTo: 1
      // 0: un-active, 1: active
    }
  }
};

// ----------- Contacts.js

module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        title: {
            type: 'string'
        },

        firstName: {
            type: 'string'
        },

        lastName: {
            type: 'string'
        },

        email: {
            type: 'string'
        },

        position: {
            type: 'string'
        },

        landlinePhone: {
            type: 'string'
        },

        mobilePhone: {
            type: 'string'
        },

        externalCompany: {
            type: 'string'
        },

        schools : {
            collection: 'schools',
            via: 'contacts',
            dominant: true
        },

        user: {
            model: 'users'
        },

        activities: {
            collection: 'activities',
            via: 'contact'
        },

        status: {
            type: 'integer',
            defaultsTo: 1
            // 0: remove, 1: active, 2: unactive
        }
    }
};
```

And here's my code when creating a new contact:

```
Contacts.create(contactData).exec(function (e1, newContact) {
    if (e1) {
      console.log("e1 ::: ", e1);
    };

    // newContact is filled with contact new data..
    console.log("Contact data has been created", newContact, schoolId);

    // Adding schools to newContact (schoolId has a value here);
    newContact.schools.add(schoolId);

    // Save
    newContact.save(function (err) { console.log('err', err) });
});
```

However, when I check on my database, `contacts` has been created but without `schools` attributes. And the related `schools` also still has no `contacts` attribute.

I've tried the following;

```
newContact.schools.add([schoolId]);
// or --
newContact.schools.add(schoolObj);
// or --
newContact.schools.add([schoolObj]);
```

I've tried to switch the `dominant` attribute between those two collections and doing the execution reversed like,

```
school.contacts.add(newContact);
```

I've also tried these solution and no lucks;

- http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/many-to-many
- https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/issues/20
- [Sails.js How to insert data into a join table (Many to Many)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29396059/sails-js-how-to-insert-data-into-a-join-table-many-to-many)

Am I missing something here? Any suggestion is appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, it attaches `schools` to `contacts`.

In `sails console`, run this:

```
Contacts.find(contactId).populateAll().exec(console.log);
```

If it prints contact along with schools array populated, data is persisted in DB. It might be in a separate collection rather than being inside `Contacts` in MongoDB.

PS: `pipeline` definition has a typo in `defaultTo` (should be `defaultsTo`)

Comment: I am so stupid.. I just realized that the many to many relationship is in another collections. Thanks for your answer..